# How to write $E(Y|X)$ as a function of $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

How to write $E(Y|X)$ as a function of $X$ ?

If for example $X$ and $Y$ are discrete valued as below

[image]

then $E(Y|X)$ should be equal to $-1+2X^2$ but I don't get it.

If I write for example $\displaystyle E(Y|X=-1)=\sum_y y\Pr(Y=y|X=-1)=\sum_y y\frac{\Pr(Y=y,X=-1)}{\Pr(X=-1)}=-1\cdot \frac{\Pr(Y=-1,X=-1)}{\Pr(X=-1)}+1\cdot \frac{\Pr(Y=1,X=-1)}{\Pr(X=-1)}=0\neq1=-1+2(-1)^2$

what goes wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is correct, but I believe you plugged in the wrong probabilities. The last part should look as follows $\space-1\cdot \frac{\Pr(Y=-1,X=-1)}{\Pr(X=-1)}+1\cdot \frac{\Pr(Y=1,X=-1)}{\Pr(X=-1)}=-1\cdot \frac{0}{\frac14}+1\cdot \frac{\frac14}{\frac14}=1=-1+2(-1)^2$.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake, but do you know how to ''derive'' the formula ?

Comment: Note that in your case $f(X)=E(Y|X)$ is a function with domain $\{-1,0,1\}$. Hence you need to compute its values for these three points to  identify it. You can do it by plugging in the values $X=-1,0,1$. The formula will be any function which takes the same values as $f(X)$ at these three points. For instance, $g(X)=|2X|-1$ can be also considered as formula for your function.

Answer (score 1):

If $X=-1$ is given, then $Y=1$ is definitely true. Note from your table that $Y=-1$ cannot happen, when $X=-1$.

Thus $Y|X=-1$ is a constant random variable, and so its mean value is $1$.

Similarly $E(Y|X=1)=1$, and $E(Y|X=0)=-1$.